# NX Build fails with NextJS and App Folders

Tags: next.js, nrwl-nx

I've set up a new NX Integrated project with the @NRWL Next plugin.
I'm using the new NextJS App folder

When I run build I get the following error:

```
The following suggested values were added to your tsconfig.json. These values can be changed to fit your project's needs:

- include was updated to add '../../dist/apps/my-project/.next/types/**/*.ts'

info  - Checking validity of types ...Failed to compile.

Type error: Cannot find module '../../../../../app/configurator/page' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem; the way I went around it was to temporarily enable the 'ignoreBuildErrors' option in the typescript config in next.config.js while I figured out the underlying issue causing that. Please not the caution in the documentation, though: "*If disabled, be sure you are running type checks as part of your build or deploy process, otherwise this can be very dangerous*."

The documentation for the 'ignoreBuildErrors' option is at this page: [Ignoring TypeScript Errors](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-typescript-errors)//nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/ignoring-typescript-errors

The underlying issue seems to be the NX 'outputPath' options in the 'project.json' config file for the development and production configurations for the 'build' target.